# Considering how the complex function $f(z) = z^2$ acts on lines in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

(a) Setting $w=f(z)$ and letting $z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$, find $u$ and $v$ as functions of $x$ and $y$.

(b) Find the image of horizontal lines $y=y_0$, where $y_0 \ne 0$, under $f(z) = z^2$. You should get a family parabolae. What is the image in the special case of $x_0 = 0$?

(c) Find the image of vertical lines $x=x_0$, where $x_0 \ne 0$, under $f(z) = z^2$. You should get a family parabolae. What is the image in the special case of $x_0 = 0)$?

$--------------------------------------$

For part (a) I'm pretty sure I use the Cauchy-Riemann equation.

For part (b) and (c) I get graphs that look similar to this (I tried to find an image as close as possible, so ignore the labels!).

[image: Graph similar to mine]

But I really struggle when translating my process into proper mathematical form. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I dont think You really need C-R for a)..

You're interested in $Re(w)$ and $Im(w)$, so $w=(x+iy)^2 = x^2+2xyi-y^2$, hence $u = Re(w) = x^2-y^2$ and $v= Im(w) = 2xy$. This tells You that the point $[x,y]$ is mapped to the point $[x^2-y^2, 2xy]$.

For b) using the previous and considering $y=y_0$ a constant you get the locus $[x^2-y_0^2, 2xy_0]$ and substituting $\overline{y} := 2xy_0$ (thinking in geometrical coordinates $\overline{x},\overline{y}$), You get the locus described as $[\frac{\overline{y}^2}{4y^2_0}-y_0^2, \overline{y}]$, hence a parabola $\overline{x} = \frac{\overline{y}^2}{4y^2_0}-y_0^2$ ($y_0$ is a real constant).

For $y_0 = 0$ You have the locus of points $[x^2,0]$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, which is the positive $x$-semiaxis.

c) is similar

Comment: What are "geometrical coordinates"?

Comment: Nothing more than "new coordinates with $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{y}$ being nex axes".